# Rails 3 - How can I visit parent's attributes in belong_to/has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, associations, belongs-to

I have a simple question in Rails 3 model:
Here are the models I have:

```
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :customer :date #blahblah..
      has_many :items
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :items



  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :order
```

So how can I reach `@item.customer` in my program?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Through the `order` association itself.

```
@item.order.customer
```

If you want to have a convenience method to access the `customer` directly from an `Item` object then you would have to write some custom accessor methods.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def customer
    self.order.customer
  end

  def customer=(new_customer)
    self.order.customer = (new_customer)
  end
end
```